# User activity tab seems to be missing successful "flag as not an answer" audits

Tags: bug, recent-activity, review-audits

[My activity tab on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/users/981045/toomai?tab=activity) shows a single [audit pass](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/2535998) (no-action-needed a good answer) followed by earning two Custodian badges (one for First Posts, one for Late Answers, don't remember which order). Where is the entry for the second audit pass (flagged a non-answer)0? I've even had a second correctly-flagged-not-an-answer audit since then and it's not showing up either.

Comment: OMG Toomai, I have lost all respect for you, knowing your rep on SO is inflated by 4 points.. !!! ;)